# Social account/external idp bind account with pre-created user using SCIM

Tags: curity

I'm trying to set up a system where pre-created users can log in using an identity provider (IDP) like Google, while still being able to retrieve data from their existing local accounts. These users have been generated with SCIM using a provisioning script.

I want to avoid triggering an unnecessary HTML-form login. How can I programmatically pre-create the link? I assume I need to provide some kind of linking value, such as the 'sub' in the external IDP or another field that can create a unique match.

I have looked at various examples that all involve HTML login + actions to populate internal tables or session information in Curity. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to avoid using local usernames and passwords during the linking process.

https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/authentication-service-admin-guide/account-linking/index.html
[https://curity.io/resources/learn/account-linking-with-social/](https://curity.io/resources/learn/account-linking-with-social)
[https://curity.io/resources/learn/account-linking-recipes/](https://curity.io/resources/learn/account-linking-recipes)

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could provision the links in the linked-accounts table.

Since Google sets the subject as an identifier which is unique to your client (PPID) you could use the email as the linked value and transform the subjet in an authentication action to be the email received by Google before running the resolve-link authentication action.

Normally, if you run the linking process directly in Curity the link would be between the local account ID and Google's identifier, but that can change in the authentication-actions pipeline.

Let me know if that helps, i can create an example if you need more info

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I was going to try to play with that table but I wasn't sure if it was the way to go. An example would be amazing to close the gap.

Comment: Hi, I have created a linked_accounts row manually through SQL pointing to the local account_id and the subject that returns google. But it doesn't work during authentication process. It just outputs google info without linking local data (linked_subject) as the tutorials suggest. Am I missing something?