# Manual creation of account link to retrieve local account attributes (Google authenticator)

Tags: curity

Following the guidelines provided here:
[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76587246/social-account-external-idp-bind-account-with-pre-created-user-using-scim)

I manually created an account_link aiming to connect with local account:

select * from "linked_accounts";

[image]

I have the google authenticator:
[image]

With this setup:
[image]

As suggested here [Curity article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/account-linking-with-social/)

I have an account matching the table value account_id:

[image]

Then i'm expecting to have the local account subject when I log in with google authenticator but the link doesn't seem to work:
[image]

I was expecting "cslues" being displayed in subject as "alice" gets displayed in the article. Isn't it meant to work like this? Do I need a matching value in both objects? isn't the link provided by the table "linked_accounts"? Finally i would like to bring more fields from the local account not just the subject but this can probably be done by other kind of action.

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you put a debug action before the `Resolve Link` action you should see only the Google attributes in the subject attributes initially:

```json
[
   {
      sub: "102269 ..."
      email: ...
      email_verified: ...
      at_hash: ...
      name: ...,
      picture: ...,
      given_name: ...,
      family_name: ...,
      locale: ...,
      subject: "102269 ..."
   }
]
```

If you put a second debug action after the `Resolve Link` action you should see the subject updated with the `username` from the accounts table:

```json
[
   {
      sub: "102269 ..."
      email: ...
      email_verified: ...
      at_hash: ...
      name: ...,
      picture: ...,
      given_name: ...,
      family_name: ...,
      locale: ...,
      subject: "cslues",
      linked_subject: "102269 ..."
   }
]
```

For this to work, your `linked_accounts` table should look like this:

```
  account_id  |   linked_account_id   | linked_account_domain_name | linking_account_manager |          
-------------+-----------------------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
 c2322cc8 ... | 102269 ...            | google-domain              | default-account-manager |
```

And your `accounts` table should look like this:

```
  account_id  |   username   |     
-------------+---------------+
 c2322cc8 ... | cslues       |
```

Please check your data against this. Also try running [Use Case 2](https://github.com/curityio/account-linking-recipes) from the account linking recipes repo, which I'm guessing you based your solution on.

**FIELDS FROM THE LOCAL ACCOUNT**

This depends where you want to use the local account fields:

- If you need such values during authentication logic you can use a `data source transformer action` - use case 4 in the above repo has a couple of examples
- If you want to issue values from the local account to tokens then a `claims value provider` is typically used

Both of these can use a `data source`, defined in the facilities menu of the Admin UI. See use case 4 in the above repo for an example.

Comment: I think my issue is related with account domains. How can I query accounts  once I have the html-form-authenticator configured within local-domain. The accounts table remains empty but created users can be queried over SCIM. Does the HSQL require some kind of domain specification or some other step that I'm missing?

Comment: Sounds like your account linking setup is now fine and data is saving correctly now. I answered the HSQLDB point in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76681311/where-are-accounts-stored-after-setting-an-account-domain/76686741#76686741).

Comment: Account linking is fine following tutorial actions but my tables in HSQL remain empty (accounts and linked_accounts) so I won't be able to replicate that with provisioning scripts.