# Where are accounts stored after setting an account domain?

Tags: curity

I want to create provisioning scripts for accounts and links but I'm facing the following issue:

1- Populate users in a basic setup without account domains through html-form:
[image]

2- Verify that the data gets populated:

[image]

It returns the users that I have created through the form.

3- Create an account domain "local-domain" and drag html-authenticator inside.(Required step in many tutorial pages):
[image]
4- Open html form again and populate new users

5-Query again accounts and it won't show the new accounts.

6- Check users by SCIM and it will return all of them (Optional):

curl  -Ssk 
-w "\n%{http_code}" 
-H "Authorization: Bearer $1" 
https://auth.curity.com:8443/user-management/Users/

So where are they registered? how can query them in HSQL?
I guess something similar happens with links.

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**YOUR QUESTION**

Accounts are stored in the accounts table. The only role of the account domain is for account linking. The account domain is stored against entries in the `linked_accounts` table. So it looks like your system is working fine. I went through your steps with a postgres database and all entries are available in the accounts table.

You may be running into some HSQLDB specific behavior that prevents the latest entries being visible. Note that HSQLDB is shipped as a convenience for developers. It is a small getting started database only, [not suitable for production](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/system-admin-guide/data-sources/jdbc.html#hsqldb). It sounds to me that you are well beyond that stage now, since you are working on advanced features.

**MY DEVELOPMENT DATABASE**

For a local development setup, I most commonly use a basic deployment of postgres. This can be useful even if you will use a different production database. Some notes here in case they are useful to you. I start with [docker options](https://github.com/curityio/account-linking-recipes/blob/main/docker-compose.yml) like these:

```yaml
curity-data:
    image: postgres:15.3
    hostname: dbserver
    ports:
     - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./data-backup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data-backup.sql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'sonepassword'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'idsvr'
```

I then edit the default data source in the facilities menu of the Admin UI to set matching properties:

```
Driver: org.postgresql.Driver
Connection String: jdbc:postgresql://dbserver/idsvr
User: ...
Password: ...
```

You can then remote to the postgres docker container and run queries:

```bash
export PGPASSWORD=somepassword && psql -p 5432 -d idsvr -U postgres
\dt;
select * from accounts;
```

You can also backup your users periodically:

```bash
export PGPASSWORD=somepassword && pg_dump -U postgres -d idsvr > /tmp/data-backup.sql
```

Comment: I think postgres as datasource is only valid in paid license. I already tried something similar and got "A license violation has occurred".

Comment: Just to get back to you on this: postgres works fine with a community  license. Eg try running the [SPA + Token Handler](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-spa-example/) repo with your license and running a login. This uses a postgres database, A license violation should only occur if you try to use more advanced features though, eg those for financial grade. Maybe look carefully at the identity server logs to see the cause of your license violation.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I will take a look

Comment: Yes, I was able to configure a postgres with community license.